# Slack messages incoming web hooks as unique message not continued

Tags: slack, slack-api

I am hitting an API to return stats of some websites, I analyse the returned values and add some of the sites to an array.

I then construct a slack message and add the array of sites to the `fields` section like this;

```
"attachments": [
                {
                    "fallback": "",
                    "color": "#E50000",
                    "author_name": "title",
                    "title": "metrics recorded",
                    "title_link": "https://mor47992.live.dynatrace.com/#dashboard;id=cc832197-3b50-489e-b2cc-afda34ab6018;gtf=l_7_DAYS",
                    "text": "more title info",
                    "fields": sites,
                    "ts": Date.now() / 1000 | 0
                }
            ]
```

This is all in a lambda which is triggered every 5 minutes, the first message comes through fine.

however subsequent messages just append to the fields section of the original message so it looks like I have delivered duplicate content in the message. is there a way to force each hit to the incoming web hook to post as a brand new message to slack?

here is an example of a followup message, notice the duplicate content.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Its a "feature" of Slack that is will automatically combine multiple message from the same user / bot without restating the user name if they are send within a short time frame.

To separate the attachments in your case would suggest to add an introduction text. Either via `text` property of the message (on same level than `attachments` property). Or by adding a `pretext` to each attachment.